# Having troubles getting a Garry's Mod private server to connect to MySQL database using MariaDB

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

Trying to get a private Garry's Mod TTT server started to test things using publicly released code (moat.gg GitHub.) Got the database setup using MariaDB and am met with errors when launching the server that I cannot figure out on my own. Zero clue what is wrong and why it isn't connecting and I am met with the error below permanently, any help is appreciated.

```
[moat_addons] addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/datastore.lua:1: Couldn't load module 
library! (The specified module could not be found.)
  1. require - [C]:-1
   2. unknown - addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/datastore.lua:1
    3. include - [C]:-1
     4. unknown - addons/moat_addons/lua/system/app/core/init.lua:607
      5. include - [C]:-1
       6. unknown - addons/moat_addons/lua/autorun/init.lua:4
```

It is just multiple of that first error where it "Couldn't load module library"

Comment: Your question doesn't specify what it is you're actually using, so I'll assume you're trying to setup some kind of Garry's Mod server with [these addons](https://github.com/colemclaren/ttt). These seem to use a library called mysqloo; have you followed the [installation instructions](https://github.com/FredyH/MySQLOO#Install-Instructions) of that library? Also, you'd likely get better help at [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/), as StackOverflow is specialized in programming questions, not game server setup.

Comment: So, what is in the line #1 of `datastore.lua` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I had used the latest mysqloo file in every location but I missed one, the only one that mattered... fixed.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you're missing the MySQLOO module required for Garry's Mod to connect to a MySQL (MariaDB too) servers.

The module can be found here: [FredyH MySQLOO](https://github.com/FredyH/MySQLOO/releases/latest) and installing is easy as picking which version your server is running i.e. Linux or Windows and dropping it into the folder called `garrysmod/garrysmod/lua/bin/` you can place both 32 and 64 bit versions if you're unsure which version your server is running.

Based on the other code you'll also want to edit the database options if you haven't already which are located in `addons/moat_addons/lua/system/cfg/sql/sv_config.lua`